# Extending a sentence with a semicolon

Tags: grammar, tone

Which version is better, grammatically? How can I improve this? Is the grammar legal? I want to extend the end of a sentence, like so-

"Life means I have a choice at every turn; every moment."

"Life means I have a choice at every turn, every moment."

Comment: The examples sound to pair rather incongruous temporal modifiers. A comma is probably sufficient for the gentle reformulatory parenthesis ("Life means I have a choice every day, every moment.") Though I'd probably show a little more emphasis in my rethink with a dash – or even a sentence fragment: "Life means I have a choice every day. Every moment!"

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the comma because the semicolon is definitely incorrect. They're technically only used to separate complete sentences.

INCORRECT: Life means I have a choice at every turn; every moment

CORRECT: Life means I have a choice at every turn; I make choices at every moment.

I also like the idea of using a dash instead!

Comment: I was writing some long winded, overly pedantic comment about the nuanced nature of semicolons and their applicability beyond the separation of independent clauses...In reality your answer is accurate and properly explains why the comma is correct in this situation. +1